# Adding Autocomplete or typehead feature to ComboBox in Access 2016

Tags: database, ms-access, combobox, autocomplete, ms-access-2016

I have an Access table that has about 500,000 records. I want to trim down the results as I type text into the ComboBox. Basically, I need a dynamic ComboBox that displays records based on each character as I type into the ComboBox.

The problem is, the underlying table for the ComboBox has about 500,000 records. 
And the ComboBox object can only display 65,000 records before it reaches it's limit, and won't preview the rest of the records. Nobody looks at 65,000 records at the same time but when any number in the middle of the entire record set is typed, the records won't display at all. Because that particular number is beyond the 65,000 limit. So i need a dynamic combobox for the whole table.

For example, if you are looking at a bunch of SSNs, instead of ComboBox displaying all the records which it can't because too many SSNs (more than 65,000 which is ComboBox limit) this is what I need.

If you type 5 in the ComboBox. The list would only display the 5-series of numbers. If you type 51 it limits the list values are the 51-series of numbers.
If you type 512 it limits the list values to the 512-series of numbers and so on. FOR THE WHOLE TABLE THOUGH, not just the first 65K.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR is implementing a second unbound text box, however, this makes querying a two step process. I am wondering if I can just do it all together.

Comment: No I wasn't either

Answer (score 2):

David W Fenton already provided a fairly detailed answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/289268/4024810). The gist:

> The simplest approach is to assign the combo box's Rowsource only after you type some characters in it. You'd do that in the combo box's OnChange event

Allen Browne's [Combos with Tens of Thousands of Records](http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html) has some other bells and whistles (abstracting the logic into a function, preventing recalculation of the RowSource if the value hasn't changed), but the basic idea is the same:

> 1. Leave the combo's RowSource property blank.
> 2. Create a function that assigns the RowSource after a minimum number of characters has been typed. Only entries matching these initial characters are loaded, so the combo's RowSource never contains more than a few hundred records.
> 3. Call this function in the combo's Change event, and the form's Current event.

If you really want to successively filter the RowSource as each character is typed, you could adapt these answers to do that. For example, you could change the test condition in the David W Fenton solution to `If Len(Me!cmbMyCombo.Text) >= 1`. For the Allen Browne solution, you could set the constant to 1 and change the line that sets `sNewStub` to: `sNewStub = Nz(sSuburb, "")`.

However, until your RowSource query is returning a chunk of numbers that is less than the row limit, you're not going to see any benefit. This is why both solutions linked above begin filtering after 2 (or 3 or 4) initial characters have been typed.