# Reading Data from Access database and adding to a combox is very slow

Tags: database, vb.net, performance, ms-access, vba

So Ive been trying to read from a large access database and the table iam trying to read from contains nearly 20000 entries, all of which are needed in the combox. With some testing I have figured out that the program slows down the longer it runs. The first 5000 are added almost instantaneously, but the next 5000 increment increase exponentially. Over all it would take about 5 minutes to load the entire thing. Am i missing something that will make it more efficient? Ive attached the function iam using below. It is in Vb.net

```
       Private Sub chkBoxPurchasedPart_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBoxPurchasedPart.CheckedChanged
        If (chkBoxPurchasedPart.Checked) Then
            chkBoxRawMaterial.Checked = False
            chkBoxSkipMaterialSelection.Checked = False
            MaterialButton.Enabled = True
            comboxMaterial.Sorted = True

            comboxMaterialHdn.Text = "AS SUPPLIED"
            comboxMaterialHdn.Enabled = False


            Dim cn As OleDbConnection
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
            Dim oConnect, oQuery As String
            oConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Y:\eng\ENG_ACCESS_DATABASES\VisibPartAttributes.mdb"
            oQuery = "SELECT * FROM VISIB_PARTMASTER_LOCAL WHERE PRODUCT_LINE LIKE '%PUR%' OR PRODUCT_LINE LIKE '%NOSTD%' AND PARTDESCR NOT LIKE '%OBSOLETE%'"

            Try
                cn.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
            Finally
                cn = New OleDbConnection(oConnect)
                cn.Open()
            End Try

            cmd = New OleDbCommand(oQuery, cn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader


            comboxMaterial.Items.Add("- - OTHER - -")

            While dr.Read()
                comboxMaterial.Items.Add(dr(0))
            End While

            dr.Close()
            cn.Close()

            Try
                Dim s As Session = Session.GetSession()
                Dim dispPart As Part = s.Parts.Display()
                Dim c As NXOpen.Assemblies.Component = dispPart.ComponentAssembly.RootComponent

                Dim children As NXOpen.Assemblies.Component() = c.GetChildren()

                Dim childMaterial As String = Nothing

                For Each child As NXOpen.Assemblies.Component In children
                    childMaterial = child.GetStringAttribute("STACKTECK_PARTN")
                    If (childMaterial.Length > 5 Or child.Name.StartsWith("PUR")) Then
                        comboxMaterial.Text = childMaterial
                    End If
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        ElseIf (chkBoxPurchasedPart.Checked = False) Then

            comboxMaterialHdn.Text = ""
            comboxMaterialHdn.Enabled = True


            txtBoxDiameter.Enabled = True

            txtBoxRoundLength.Enabled = True

            txtBoxInnerDiameter.Enabled = True

            txtBoxLength.Enabled = True

            txtBoxWidth.Enabled = True

            txtBoxThickness.Enabled = True

            MaterialButton.Enabled = False
            txtBoxVisMaterial.Text = ""
            txtBoxVisMaterialDescription.Text = ""
            txtBoxEachQuantity.Text = ""
            txtBoxTotalQuantity.Text = ""
            txtBoxUnitOfMeasure.Text = ""
            comboxMaterial.Sorted = False

            comboxMaterial.Items.Clear()
            comboxMaterial.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: you NEED 20,000 entries in a combobox?

Comment: That's a criminal try-catch you have there.

Comment: I know it sounds dumb, but yes, It is a list of parts the designers at my company can use, and they refuse to have anything lacking.

Comment: I would suggest a search box that searches for items instead of having them all in there at the same time.

Comment: 20K items in a combobox is useless. If your designers insist they be there, then let them wait while they load. The Windows combobox was never intended to display 20K items in a single list, and it's performance is going to be slow when adding (and using) that many items. It also fragments memory terribly when they're being loaded due to many reallocations.

Comment: Its not even my code, was written by a previous intern, I was hoping to not rewrite the entire thing

Comment: For starters you could use a DataSource rather than tediously creating anf adding to a new collection

Comment: `Its not even my code, was written by a previous intern` -- That is irrelevant.  This statement implies that you are an intern.  The point of being a intern is to get real-world experience and it does not get any more real than maintaining code that you did not write.  You are likely being evaluated to see if you have have the skills to identify performance issues.  So what have you done so far to identify the parts of this code that are taking the most time?  Also look at the [ComboBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.beginupdate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future having a similar issue, the combobox wasnt the problem, the previous designer had the AutoCompleteMode set to suggest and append which slowed the entire process down. Disable it and your program should speed up.

Answer (score 0):

I would only load the combo-box records after the first 3 or 4 characters have been entered. This should drastically reduce the number of records being returned, and a still allow the autocomplete to work.

This thread has code to assist you : [get 65K records only listed in combo box from a table of 155K records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279148/get-65k-records-only-listed-in-combo-box-from-a-table-of-155k-records)