# Conditional formatting prevents combobox dropdown on continuous form

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following code filters the dropdown list of a combobox in a continuous subform and allows the user to move up and down the dropdown to select data

```
'Move through the dropdown using up/down arrow keys
Private Sub IngCombo_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

   Dim MsgBoxResponse As String
      Select Case KeyCode
      'Tab button is pressed with "" in the field. Access returns a warning message if not dealt with
       Case 9 'Tab Button
         If Me.IngCombo.Text = "" Then
            MsgBoxResponse = MsgBox("Ingredient you entered is not in the list" & vbCrLf & "Would you like to try again?", vbYesNo, "Ingredient not recognised")
            Select Case MsgBoxResponse
               Case Is = 6
                  KeyCode = 0
               Case Is = 7
                  KeyCode = 0
                  Me.Undo
            End Select
         End If

      Case vbKeyDown
         Me.IngCombo.Selected(Me.IngCombo.ListIndex + 1) = True
         KeyCode = 0
         Me.IngCombo.DropDown

      Case vbKeyUp
         Me.IngCombo.Selected(Me.IngCombo.ListIndex - 1) = True
         KeyCode = 0
         Me.IngCombo.DropDown

      Case vbKeyEscape
         Me.IngCombo.Text = ""
         Me.Undo
      End Select
End Sub

Private Sub IngCombo_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
   'Filter dropdown to match what the user has typed
   'This combo's control source is the IngredientID, but the ID is hidden, hence the SQL selects both the ID and Ingredient text
   Dim UserText As String

   If Len(Me.IngCombo.Text) > 0 Then
      UserText = Me.IngCombo.Text
      Me.IngCombo.RowSource = "SELECT IngredientsTbl.IngredientID, IngredientsTbl.Ingredient " _
                            & "FROM IngredientsTbl WHERE (((IngredientsTbl.Ingredient) LIKE '*" & UserText & "*'));"
      If Me.IngCombo.ListCount > 0 Then
         Me.IngCombo.DropDown
      End If
   Else
      Me.IngCombo.RowSource = "SELECT IngredientsTbl.IngredientID, IngredientsTbl.Ingredient " _
                            & "FROM IngredientsTbl;"
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub IngCombo_LostFocus()
Me.IngCombo.RowSource = "SELECT IngredientsTbl.IngredientID, IngredientsTbl.Ingredient " _
                              & "FROM IngredientsTbl ORDER BY IngredientsTbl.Ingredient;"
End Sub

'If user types string that is found by the 'Key Up' routine above but is in the middle of a string i.e. 'milk' is typed and 'buttermilk' is highlighted
'Then pressing tab results in the not in list error
Private Sub IngCombo_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
      MsgBox "No ingredient matches your search", vbOKOnly, "Nothing Found"
      Me.IngCombo = ""
      Response = acDataErrContinue
End Sub
```

This works as intended.

I then add a conditional format, [text19]>50, to the ‘IngCombo’ combobox. This also works as intended but changes the behaviour of the 'IngCombo' combobox. The dropdown no longer appears, and when the user types in the ‘IngCombo’ field of a new record, it has the effect of filtering the text in the ‘IngCombo’ field of the other records of the continuous form. Eg if the user types ‘mint’, then records that contain mint in ‘IngCombo’ are shown, but all the others are blank.
The word ‘calculating’ appears momentarily in the bottom left, replacing the words 'form view' after a key is pressed. I assume this is the conditional formatting doing its work and disrupting the code, as ‘calculating’ does not appear when there is no conditional formatting.

Is there a way of maintaining the functionailty of the code and also having the conditional formating

Update after June7's comment that referenced Allen Browne code.Tried moving code into a Private Sub that is called from the combo's Change event

```
 Private Sub IngCombo_Change()
   Dim Cmbo As ComboBox
   Set Cmbo = Me.IngCombo
   Dim NewText As String
   NewText = Cmbo.Text
   Call ReloadIngCombo(NewText)
End Sub

Private Sub ReloadIngCombo(UserText As String)
   If Len(UserText) > 1 Then
      Me.IngCombo.RowSource = "SELECT IngredientsTbl.IngredientID, IngredientsTbl.Ingredient " _
                            & "FROM IngredientsTbl WHERE (((IngredientsTbl.Ingredient) LIKE '*" & UserText & "*'));"
      If Me.IngCombo.ListCount > 0 Then
         Me.IngCombo.DropDown
      End If
   Else
      Me.IngCombo.RowSource = "SELECT IngredientsTbl.IngredientID, IngredientsTbl.Ingredient " _
                            & "FROM IngredientsTbl;"
   End If
End Sub
```

This works as intended. Adding a conditional format to the combobox prevents the dropdowns being shown to the user

Comment: Suggest you set breakpoints and step debug. I expect issue will be with the Key events. I have never used them. I have used GotFocus and Enter events to activate dropdown.

Comment: I tested combobox with Conditional Formatting and only GotFocus procedure and works just fine. Why do you need the Key events? I can use up/down cursor keys to move through list without them.

Comment: I wanted key events to filter the list as the user types. Yes, you can use the up/down cursor keys to move through the entire list, but my list is a very long list of ingredients for a recipe database. If the user types 'sugar' for example, I'd like the dropdown to show only the data with 'sugar' included. Therefore easier to find, as sugar could be mid way through the wording ie granulated sugar, soft brown sugar etc, and also highlights to the user that there is in fact several types of sugar, minimising errors.

Comment: How long is list? I have comboboxes with several thousand items and using the combobox AutoExpand property is adequate for me. However, consider using combobox Change event instead of Key events. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279148/get-65k-records-only-listed-in-combo-box-from-a-table-of-155k-records and http://allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html

Comment: When complete the list will contain a few hundred items. Without any code the combobox does move the user to the item in the list that matches what is typed, but only the beginning of the string. Placing the code in the Change event results in the same issues if a conditional format is used as well. Surely it is possible to use code wherever one would like and still be able to use the conditional formatting function alongside it?

Comment: I tested Allen Browne's code along with Conditional Formatting on combobox and it all works. So the answer to your question is "Yes".

Comment: The issue of blank records is well known and often discussed. This is to be expected with a combobox that uses alias (saves ID but displays text) when that combobox list is filtered. The descriptive data is not available for display for records with the ID of items filtered out. Research "conditional combobox".

Comment: Sorry, research "cascading combobox".